# Is it true that an ideal is prime iff the reduced Gröbner basis contains irreducible polynomials

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, groebner-basis

Say $P$ is an ideal of the ring $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ where $k$ is any field. Moreover say $G$ is a reduced Gröbner basis of $P$ (for some monomial ordering). Is it true that $P$ is prime if and only if $f$ is irreducible for any $f\in G$? If it is false, does the claim hold for some monomial ordering (like an elimination order)?

What about if $k$ is algebraically closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample for the case where $k$ is not algebraically closed . . .

In the ring $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, consider the ideal 
$$I = (x^2 + 1,y^2 + 1)$$
The ideal $I$ is not a prime ideal, but is already Groebner reduced for any monomial ordering.

Comment: Do you have a comment for $k=\overline{k}$?

Comment: I suspect a counterexample is also possible for the case where $k$ is algebraically closed, but off hand, I don't see one.

Comment: Maybe I can ask one more question. Is it true that if $I\subset J$ then $|G|\leq |H|$ where $G$ and $H$ are reduced Gröbner bases of $I$ and $J$ respectively?

Comment: BTW, it seems like if $P$ is prime then $G$ cannot have a reducible polynomial $f$, right? Otherwise one of the irreducible factors of $f$ would be in $P$ and then we cannot say that $G$ is a reduced Gröbner basis in this case.

Comment: On your last comment, yes of course. On the comment before that, I don't think so, but that would be a nice new question to post.